# Generating statistics with mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, database

How can I write an sql statement that returns a list of how many `students` had `lessons` for each of the last 12 months?

so I would expect output something like:

```
+--------+----------------+
| Month  | No of Students |
+--------+----------------+
| Oct 08 |  12            |
| ...    |  ...           |
| ...    |  ...           |
| Sep 09 |  15            |
+-------------------------+
```

edit: relevant schema -

```
lessons{student_id:INT, time:DATE}
student{id:INT, person_id:INT}
```

Students may take any number of lessons in a given month, so I'm not interested in how many lessons were in a month but how many students took lessons in that month

Comment: You need to provide a schema. This also sounds a lot like homework.

Comment: It's not homework - I'm freelancing for a guy who runs a music tuition service.  The the only schema that you need is that there is a lessons table with a FK to students, and the time the lesson took place

Comment: It's still hard to answer the question w/o the schema. It's also very helpful to ask a precise and complete question, as that makes it easier to give an answer.

Comment: Try to filter out the stuff that's unnecessary. For instance, you didn't have to say "students" and "lessons", you could have just asked how to count the number of elements in a table that match a condition. Students who aren't interested in learning typically include unnecessary information, because they just copy from the homework sheet to SO, and this looks like it.

Comment: you are wrong - I wasn't sure if it was necessary because of my requirement that the students should be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) inside of a [`group by`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to achieve the results you're looking for, since you just want to do a `count distinct`.

```
select
    date_format(`time`, '%b %y') as `Month`,
    count(distinct student_id) as NumberOfStudents
from
    lessons
where
    `time` >= date_add(date_add(current_date interval -12 months) 
                  interval (-1)*(day(current_date)+1) days)
group by
    date_format(`time`, '%b %y')
```

If there can be multiple `student_id` for one `person_id`, and what you're *really* interested in is the count of unique `person_id`s, then you can do this:

```
select
    date_format(l.`time`, '%b %y') as `Month`,
    count(distinct s.person_id) as NumberOfPeople
from
    lessons l
    inner join students s on
        l.student_id = s.id
where
    l.`time` >= dateadd(dateadd(current_date interval -12 months) 
                  interval (-1)*(day(current_date)+1) days)
group by
    date_format(l.`time`, '%b %y')
```

Comment: there seems to be a syntax error around:     `time` >= dateadd(dateadd(current_date interval -12 months) 
                  interval (-1)*(day(current_date)+1) days)

Comment: also how do I make it show 0 if there were no lessons that month?

Comment: correct syntax is: `time` >= date_add(date_add(current_date, interval -12 month), interval (-1)*(day(current_date)+1) day)

Comment: @Robert: You'd need to load a month table and `cross join` to that in order to get months that would be missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (student_id int(10), month int(4), year int(4));

INSERT INTO tmp
SELECT DISTINCT student.id, MONTH(time), YEAR(time)
FROM lessons INNER JOIN student ON lessons.student_id = student.id
WHERE PERIOD_ADD(time,12) > NOW();

SELECT count(*) FROM tmp
GROUP BY MONTH(month), YEAR(year);

DROP TABLE tmp;
```

Comment: There is a ) missing after YEAR(date).

Comment: It also doesn't take into account that multiple students may have lessons on the same day

Comment: Query changed against your case.